# How to scale my hal ratiometric sensor output?

Tags: analog, hall-effect, scaling

I have a UGN3505 sensor that converts magnetic flux to voltage. The output at zero magnetic flux is 2.5V and the difference in the flux depending on the polarity varies the voltage from 2.5V.
I want a circuit that keeps the 2.5V as the normal output but let me select the sensitivity of the sensor to magnetic flux.
I know I can use an MCU to read this voltage and scale the output. But is it possible to do so with no MCU?

Comment: Masoud, are you done with this question now? If not, please leave a comment if you need more help.

Comment: Dear Andy I've made a PCB to test it. not tested yet I will report the result here. thanks

Answer (score 1):

> *I know I can use an MCU to read this voltage and scale the output. But
> is it possible to do so with no MCU?*

Probably the simplest is this op-amp circuit: -

[image]

You need to create a 2.5 volt reference voltage and that could be from a potential divider from a stable supply voltage or, better still by using a voltage reference chip (if the supply voltages can vary a bit).

When Vin is 2.5 volts, Vout will also be 2.5 volts. If Vin rises (say) 100 mV, then the op-amp output lowers by 100 mV * R2 / R1. Thus you have gain (the ratio of R2 to R1). The output is inverting but that shouldn't be a problem.

So if R2/R1 = 10 when the input voltage is 2.6 volts absolute, the output will be 1.5 volts. If the input voltage is 2.4 volts, the output will be 3.5 volts.

You can also use an op-amp to create a non-inverting version: -

[image]

The gain of this circuit is 1 + R2/R1 so, if R2/R1 = 10, the gain is 11. So with 2.6 volts at the input, the output will be 2.6 volts. With 2.4 volts at the input, the output will 1.4 volts.